# Topology Qualifying Exam Problem 42

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was going through some old qualifying exam problems and I have been struggling with this one. Any help would be great, thanks.

> Consider the 2-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ and the topological space
>   $X = \mathbb{T}^2 × [−, 1, 1]/ ∼$
>   where $(x,t) ∼ (x',t')$ if either $(x,t) = (x',t')$, or $t = t'\in \{−1,1\}$.
>   Compute $H^*(X; \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Where could I find the other 41?

Comment: What you have here is the unbased suspension (I think) of $\mathbb T^2$.  Let $A=\{(x,t)\mid t<2/3\}$ and $B=\{(x,t)\mid t>1/3\}$  Then $X=A\cup B$, $A\cap B$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb T^2$, and both $A$ and $B$ are contractible.  Now apply Mayer-Vietoris.

Comment: @Aaron Is there an easy way to see the ring structure of the cohomology?

Comment: @Potato I feel that there should be an easy way of describing the cohomology ring of a suspension in terms of the cohomology ring of the original space.  Unfortunately I don't know it.  If I find something, I will write up an answer.

Comment: @Aaron Perhaps problem 3 on this homework assignment is relevant? http://www.stanford.edu/class/math215b/Sol6.pdf

Comment: @Aaron So the cup product is trivial and there isn't any interesting ring structure.